# If I start my app on reboot, MyApp crashes after few seconds

Tags: c#, windows-7, crash, registry, boot

I'm running on Windows 7 and I've a problem with my app at boot.
Within my app I use some threads and external dll (sqlite3.dll, etc...). 
I've included these lines at first of my start.exe file:

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
String p = System.Environment.CommandLine.Replace("vshost.","");
String pp = p.Remove(p.Length-1);
rkApp.SetValue("MyAPP", pp);
```

If I start my app manually from exe file (or with VisualStudio) works correctly.
If I start my app on reboot, MyApp crashes after few seconds.

Why I've this problem?

EDIT:
I've attached crash log:

```
Descrizione
Percorso dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore:    C:\Users\Francesco\DynInst\bin\start.exe

Firma del problema
Nome evento problema:   APPCRASH
Nome applicazione:  start.exe
Versione applicazione:  1.0.0.0
Timestamp applicazione: 4d2061b9
Nome modulo con errori: KERNELBASE.dll
Versione modulo con errori: 6.1.7600.16385
Timestamp modulo con errori:    4a5bdaae
Codice eccezione:   e0434f4d
Offset eccezione:   00009617
Versione SO:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
ID impostazioni locali: 1040
Informazioni aggiuntive 1:  0a9e
Ulteriori informazioni 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Ulteriori informazioni 3:   0a9e
Ulteriori informazioni 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Ulteriori informazioni sul problema
ID bucket:  2250313277
```

Comment: @Cecco What he means is that you haven't voted on any posts. You should help the system work by voting up useful questions and answers by clicking the up-arrow next to them. I suggest you read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). @Mitch Please don't make suggestions like that without giving advice on how. At the very least link to the faq.

Comment: For starters, some information on the crash itself might help. Say, a stack trace. If you have trouble debugging your app, put a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() on the first line.

Comment: Thanks Rytmis. I'm a newbie of Visual Studio, can you explain me how I can use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()?

Comment: You put that at the beginning of your code. What happens is that when the runtime executes that line, it invokes the system debugger. It pops up a dialog asking you which debugger you want to use, at which point you can select Visual Studio and it launches and attaches to the running process. That way, you can get the best of both worlds: the process runs at startup, but you can still debug from Visual Studio.

Comment: I suppose that this method has this behaviour. But when I add this line, Windows load a dialog with indeterminate progress bar that notify me that user has placed a "debug point", but after this dialog dismiss and Windows show me "Error with start.exe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved my issue.
FYI: If you use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() on application that should be start on boot, we have to verify correct path (actually is windows/system).

Thanks for your help! With Dynamic debug all works correctly!